# Any sloka/strota to improve my skills?

Tags: scripture, vedas, shiva, devi, kali

I want to be an actor but my acting skills aren't that great is there any sloka/strota/prayer which can help me with it

Comment: How about doing regular practice and hard work for improving your skills.

Comment: @Savdy been doing that already

Comment: Abhinav Raj, Practice makes a man perfect. Do it till you are perfect. There is no shortcut for hard work. B.G. 2.47.: कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन ।
मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूर्मा ते सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि ॥ ४७ ॥

Comment: I am giving this as answer rest is upto you.

Comment: Il Om Tat Sat ll

Comment: No idea but yeah, maybe just work really hard & try to always be a good person & treat everyone with lotsa kindness & respect, try just be really hardworking honest person. Then in your religious stuffs do prayers w/ sincere & lotsa gratitude 

Answer (score 1):

Practice makes a man perfect. Do it till you are perfect. There is no shortcut for hard work.

**B.G. 2.47.:**

> *कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन । मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूर्मा ते सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि ॥ ४७ ॥*
>
> ***You have only right to your actions, never to the fruits (of the action).  Let not the fruits of action be thy motive, nor let thy attachment be to inaction (Akarman).***

Best of Luck. ..